# How can I test if a link exists with Selenium IDE?

Tags: url, selenium, ide, hyperlink, selenium-ide

I'm a beginner user of Selenium IDE. I need a help to create a test case that as input gets URL of Home page, and runs tests in loop on existence for both ALL links from the Home page and from all inner pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify a link by using a very simple locator eg.  link=Home
Or link=logout  etc.